# Limit is not actually evaluated, but wolframalpha does

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to evaluate the limit $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ of the function $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+\tfrac{a^2}{4x(a-x)}\sin^2 \left(b\sqrt{a-x}  \right)}$ using mathematica, and it should yield $\dfrac{1}{1+ab^2/4}$, as it does using

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim+x-%3Ea+%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2B%5Ctfrac%7Ba%5E2%7D%7B4x%28a-x%29%7D%5Csin%5E2+%5Cleft%28b%5Csqrt%7Ba-x%7D++%5Cright%29%7D).
However, throwing the following code into Mathematica

```
f[x_] := 1/(1 + (1/4*(a^2/(x*(a - x))) (sin^2 [sqrt (x - a)])))
Limit[f[x], x -> a]
```

leaves me with the unevaluated limit

[image: 1].

I've read here and there how some limits are causing problems with mathematica, and how one should seperate multiplied variables by a space character, but even though I tried to follow these best practice guidelines, I'm left clueless with my limit. Help, anyone?

Comment: You notation in the question `f[x_] := 1/(1 + (1/4*(a^2/(x*(a - x))) (sin^2 [sqrt (x - a)])))` differs from your notation in W|A.

Comment: Mathematica is not free form (it has a well defined syntax) so you would need to make explicit use of the Wolfram|Alpha input option for the expression shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Correcting your syntax and assuming `a` and `b` real, one obtains

```
f[x_] := 1/(1 + (1/4*(a^2/(x*(a - x))) *Sin[b*Sqrt [x - a]]^2))
Limit[f[x], x -> a, Assumptions -> {a,b} > -Infinity]
```

> `4/(4 - a b^2)`

There are problems with branches if `a` is assumed complex.

Addition.

```
g[x_] := 1/(1 + (1/4*(a^2/(x*(x - a)))*Sin[b*Sqrt[x - a]]^2))
Limit[g[x], x -> a, Assumptions -> {a, b} > -Infinity]
```

> `4/(4 + a b^2)`

Comment: I don't quite get your Assumption syntax; What is `>` before infinity?

Comment: @Sved:`a>-Infinity` means `a\[Element] Reals`. Such a notation is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] := 1/(1 + a^2/(4 x (a - x)) Sin[b Sqrt[a - x]]^2)

Limit[f[x], x -> a]
```

$$\frac{4}{a b^2+4}$$

Comment: @user64494 Adding the Real assumption for {a,b} doesn't change the answer. Are there options that can be used to improve it using automated means?

Comment: All that is not so simple: `Limit[1/(1 + a^2/(4 x (a - x)) Sin[b Sqrt[a - x]]^2), x -> a, 
 Direction -> Complexes]` is spinning on my comp.